# Gamma distribution and applications

Tags: references, gamma-distribution, application

I'm looking for references to read about gamma distribution and applications in industry or in quality control.
I had a look at statistical methods for reliability data (Meeker and Escobar). It has some good background about gamma and other lifetime distributions but I couldn't find examples of the applications.

Comment: Maybe:  https://www.amazon.co.uk/Handbook-Exponential-Distributions-Engineers-Scientists-ebook/dp/B009TGC1NK/ref=sr_1_2/257-1260855-1379261?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1506854559&sr=1-2&keywords=9780203490280

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is an single application of the gamma distribution under monotonic decreasing conditions with a heavier than exponential tail to first order pharmacokinetics drugs and for quantifying kidney function in multiple papers:

[Tikhonov adaptively regularized gamma variate fitting to assess plasma clearance of inert renal markers](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10928-010-9167-z)

[Validation of Tikhonov adaptively regularized gamma variate fitting with 24-h plasma clearance in cirrhotic patients with ascites](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00259-011-1887-9)

[Accurate and precise plasma clearance measurement using four 99mTc-DTPA plasma samples over 4 h](http://journals.lww.com/nuclearmedicinecomm/Citation/2016/01000/Accurate_and_precise_plasma_clearance_measurement.12.aspx)

[Time Varying Apparent Volume of Distribution and Drug Half-Lives Following Intravenous Bolus Injections](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0158798)

If I bump into others, I will add on.